# Переопределение equals() в анонимном классе с дополнительной переменной

Tags: java

Например, создаю анонимный класс

```
new Object() {
    private int c;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return c == (?cast?) obj.c;
    }
};
```

К чему я должен привсти `obj`?

Comment: `Object` к `int`? К примитивному типу? %)

Comment: Ну чисто в теории, можно рефлексией достать эту переменную. Но лучше нормальный класс сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле в java можно получить несколько объектов одного и того же анонимного класса, но вот воспользоваться этим анонимны классом для их сравнения не выйдет, потому что так они работают и с этим надо смириться))).

Поэтому можешь не беспокоиться на этот счет, а если хочешь сравнивать разные экземпляры анонимных классов, зная что они по структуре своей одинаковые переопредели в них метод для получения хеш кода и переопредели equals так, чтобы он эти хеши сравнивал, приведу пример этой реализации первым. А потом будут примеры с анонимными классами

```
MyAbstractClass obj = new MyAbstractClass() {
        public Integer a = 5;
        public String c = "sadfdsf";

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return a.hashCode() + c.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj.getClass().isAnonymousClass() && obj instanceof MyAbstractClass)
                return this.hashCode() == obj.hashCode();
            else
                return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.getClass().getName();
        }
    };


    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {

        objects.add((MyAbstractClass) obj.clone());
    }
    for (Object o : objects) {
        System.out.println(o + "     " + obj.equals(o));
    }
```

Вот тут вывод, и пожелание не переопределять хешкод так, как это сделал я (просто суммировал хеши) а почитать про эту тему и выбрать более оптимальную реализацию.

```
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
```

Ниже будут примеры с способами получить объекты одно и того же анонимного типа:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, CloneNotSupportedException {
    List<MyAbstractClass> objects = new ArrayList<>(5);
    MyAbstractClass obj = new MyAbstractClass() {
        public Integer a = 5;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.getClass().getName();
        }
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        MyAbstractClass obj2 = new MyAbstractClass() {
            public Integer a = 5;

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return this.getClass().getName();
            }
        };
        objects.add(obj2);
    }
    for (Object o : objects) {
        System.out.println(o + "     " + obj.getClass().equals(o.getClass()));
    }
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

Вывод будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
Solution$2     false
Solution$2     false
Solution$2     false
Solution$2     false
Solution$2     false
Solution$1
```

Из него очевидно, что в теле цикла создавались объекты одного и того же анонимного класса и у них один тип, но анонимный класс описанный ранее, до входа в цикл имеет другое имя и соответственно это другой класс. Это работает таким образом потому что этот механизм схож с тем, как если бы java встречая в коде анонимный класс автоматически генерировала для него файл и объявляла его там как он описан в коде и сама присваивала ему имя по какому либо шаблону, а в коде оставляла ссылку на этот ею объявленный класс.

Следующий пример:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>(5);
    Object obj = new Object() {
        public int a;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.getClass().getName();
        }
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {

        objects.add(obj.getClass().newInstance());
    }
    for (Object o : objects) {
        System.out.println(o + "     " + obj.getClass().equals(o.getClass()));
    }
}
```

Аналогичная ситуация.

```
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
```

Можно так же и клонированием, почему нет

```
public class MyAbstractClass implements Cloneable {
    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, CloneNotSupportedException {
    List<MyAbstractClass> objects = new ArrayList<>(5);
    MyAbstractClass obj = new MyAbstractClass() {
        public int a;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.getClass().getName();
        }
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {

        objects.add((MyAbstractClass) obj.clone());
    }
    for (Object o : objects) {
        System.out.println(o + "     " + obj.getClass().equals(o.getClass()));
    }
}

Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
Solution$1     true
```

Comment: Спасибо за столь развернутый ответ. Мне достаточно было первого предложения))). Но может кому-то пригодится еще.

Answer (score 0):

В Яве этот тип тебе не доступен. Более того, в твоём случае достаточно сравнить ссылки this и obj, потому что другого объекта с таким типом (кроме this) все равно не будет. Даже сли ты в следующей строке создашь такой же анонимный класс с таким же полем, с точки зрения Явы это будут два разных анонимных класса.

Comment: А если этот код в for находится? Или где-то еще и вызывается несколько раз.

Comment: Ну если объекты в `for` создаются, то тип они должны иметь тот же самый, который тебе всё равно не доступен.